# How to copy entire content of a local disk in python 3.6?

Tags: copy

I want to create a `.py` file in **Python 3.6** that will copy entire local disk partition from my PC (*partition D*) to **external** hard drive(*partition E*). I only managed to copy folders with `distutils copytree` command like this:

```
copy_tree(r"D:\\Myfolder", "E:\\SAVE\\Myfolder", update = True)
```

But I want the program to copy the entire partition with all folders subfolders and files.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer:

```
import distutils
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
copy_tree(r"D:\\", "E:\\SAVE\\Myfolder", update = True)`
```

This command will copy all folders from local disk to other location.

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html)